# Background turns white when i scroll down, where am I goign wrong? (I'm new to this)

Tags: css, image, html, background

My problem is that my background to my website always turns white whenever I scroll down.

```
<div align="center"><img src="bakrund.jpg" class="bg"></div>

.bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -5000;
}
```

Comment: The div attribute of align isn't a real thing. Height of 100% won't likely do much for you. Should the image actually be a background image? 

Please create a demo like in JS Bin to show us exactly what you're dealing with!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the background attribute of body in your css to define the background image, like this:

```
body
{
    background-image:url('bakrund.jpg');
}
```

Don't try to hack it in using a div.

Comment: Yea, the thing is that my background is a gradient. I had used the one u showed me before, but it would only repeat the picture again on the right side. the div code made that problem go away,, but it also created a new one. which i explained in my former question. // The idiot from before.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to set a background image do this

```
    <style>body { background-image:url("YOURURL"); } </style>
```

It's much easier and is a lot more professional.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the background to your website - it's the background to a div element...  If you're wanting to set the background of your page, you need to change the CSS in your  element.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the position to fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 body
 {
     background-image:url('bakrund.jpg');
     background-size: cover;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting your height to 100vh?

```
html {
    height: 100vh;
}
```